How do I retrieve the value of ReceivedFileName from the Context Property?
We are running more than 200 applications in our BizTalk environment. We frequently face suspended inbound messages due to issues like timeouts.
We need to reprocess all of them. For that, we need the ReceivedFileName from the context properties of the messages.
We don't want to touch/modify the running applications.
Can we find that information anywhere in the SQL databases? Or are there other approaches, such as using PowerShell?

You will probably have to make at least some changes, as the PowerShell script that I know of will just save it as the message GUID.  Saving from either the BizTalk Admin Console, and I believe also using the BHM tool will do the same.
Changes needed.

Enable Routing for failed messages on the receive and send ports
Have a new File send port that subscribes to those failed messages. ErrorReport.FailureCode Exists

On that send port use the %SourceFileName% macro on the send port.

